# How to display a list of multiple model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a social networking media like Facebook.
Users can create daily posts and events.

In timeline, I want to display a combined list of `@post` and `@event`. Can I build that on Rails?

How about this below in controller:

```
@feed = Post.all + Event.all
```

And I should divide each thumbnail view also.

[image]

So multiple item combined.

Comment: `@posts = Post.all` `@events = Event.all` then just iterate through the items to build in view as you need?

Comment: @Vbp Sure, I want to build that. `@event` and `@post` are listed with sort by created time. In a feed, event -> post -> post -> event.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `In a feed, event -> post -> post -> event.` what are your requirements? Are you just trying to display a list of events and list of posts on view?

Comment: @Vbp I have added an image in my question. So In the same feed, I want to list both event item and post item sorted by created time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding every single Post and Event to an array on memory es really dangerous, don't do that!

I can think of 2 solutions for your problem.

---

1- The easiest

Add an extra model with a polymorphic association to a Post or an Event and the created_at every time you create one of them. Then you can sort and paginate that extra model at database level. This way you won't have memory problems.

You could have some helper method to preload the post and events of that result set to prevent an N+1 queries problem since you can't use includes/references on polymorphic associations.

Pros: easy to implement

Cons: adds an extra model, you need to implement the preload of information to prevent N+1 queries, if you need to add some where statement you'll have to copy the data or join the table with the others.

---

2- The hardest

Use a UNION query with both tables and return the necesary fields just to display them.

```
union_qry = "(SELECT 'Post', id, created_at, '' as title, '' as place FROM posts) UNION (SELECT 'Event', id, created_at, title, place FROM events)"

arr = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("#{search_qry} ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT #{per} OFFSET #{offset}") #note the per and offset if you need pagination
```

That query will return a MySQL::Result that you can iterate and for each record you'll have an array like:

```
['Post', post_id, post_created_at, '', '']
```

or

```
['Event', event_id, event_created_at, event_title, event_place]
```

With those arrays you can build your list of Post+Event, if you need more data just add that to the UNION statement.

Pros: no need for an extra element, no need to repeat info, you can use where on other fields

Cons: it's far from ActiveRecord, no nice queries, no nice ActiveRecor object

---

Personally I prefer option 2, it's more flexible, but option 1 is easier.

Comment: Thanks so much @arieljuod I really appreciate that, I'm still beginner but I have decided to try to build with the hardest one.

Comment: Only use Option 1 if you know for sure you won't have too many rows. Otherwise, use Option 2 (or create another model to hold a reference to each item in the list (e.g newsfeed))

Answer (score -1):

Here's a very simple implementation of what you're asking for:

```
@feed = [*Post.all, *Event.all].sort_by(&:created_at)
```

Then in your view:

```
@feed.each do |thing|
  # thing can be a Post or an Event
end
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! But I want to ask you, how can I divide a partial?
Because Post has title and content, but Event has title, content, date and place.
So they may be different.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if you're asking how to display the posts and events in your loop, you could make a partial for each type: _post.html.erb and _event.html.erb. Then, in your loop (in e.g. index.html.erb), render the partial that corresponds to the current object type.

Comment: Happy to help out

Comment: Be careful with this, if you have too many posts and events `Post.all` and `Event.all` will load ALL of them on memory to sort them. It's a really dangerous approach, it does not scale.

Comment: hey @k10a , when you display them in the frontend, you need to check its type, when it is "Post", you display its title or content, when it is "Event", you display its title/content/date and place. How "Post" and "Event" generated, you can see arieljuod 's answer.

Comment: Thanks @Spark.Bao I'll consider that more

Comment: Downvoting because if you have 1 million rows, you'll put everything in memory which is not good. This one works if you know for sure you won't have too many rows. Good alternatives: use an UNION (pure SQL or Arel), or create another model to hold a reference to each item in the list (e.g newsfeed).